# how to fix asp core mvc deployment on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

Well, I have an asp.net core (v2.1) mvc project, and i tried to deploy it on iis, when i launch my website, i can see my home page, so when i try to route to another page, an error display on my screen "An error occurred while processing your request."

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Uao.jpg)

i see some solution and i tried it, like add ASPCORE_ENVIRONMENT to my web.config or give permission to folders.

please help!! and thank you

Comment: Enable developer exceptions to see the actual error.

Comment: Open a command prompt to your site directory and run `dotnet MyApp.dll`. This will run the app within the console window and make it available at `localhost:5000` by default. Browse to the page causing the issue, and when it errors out, you'll be able to see the exception and stack trace in the console window. If you can't figure out how to solve it on your own, edit your question to include both the exception and stacktrace.

Comment: Could you enable `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in you startup Configure method out of  `env.IsDevelopment()` to make it work for IIS ? It will show detailed error after you republish and route to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Manager and click on Application Pools.  Make sure the Application Pool your MVC app is running under is set to .NET CLR version is 4 and the pipeline mode is Integrated.